# What's this visual novel with two girls cuddling?

Tags: clover-days

[image]

I'm looking for the title of this VN. I tried reverse image searching but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 6):

It's from [**Clover Day's**](https://vndb.org/v13325). The blonde girl is Takakura Anzu, and the black haired girl is Takakura Anri.

[image]